# Cloning JS generated DIV to non generated DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bit of what seems like a complicated issue(to me at least)

I've got an external javascript file generating html content for me. It's for tweets. It gives each one a individual ID, which I can see in the browser but of which is obviously not in my index.html.

The JS generates something like this in the browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTZQB.png

Heres the generated div

```
<div class="twitter-article" id="tw1"><div class="twitter-pic"><a href="https://twitter.com/jdrawsthings"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/461533054800900097/5h4n1K31_normal.jpeg" twitter-feed-icon.png"="" width="42" height="42" alt="twitter icon"></a></div><div class="twitter-text"><p><span class="tweetprofilelink"><strong><a href="https://twitter.com/jdrawsthings">JGD</a></strong><br> <a href="https://twitter.com/jdrawsthings">@jdrawsthings</a></span></p><b><span class="tweet-time"><a href="https://twitter.com/jdrawsthings/status/462738657196376064"></a></span></b><a href="https://twitter.com/jdrawsthings/status/462738657196376064"><d>2h,&nbsp;&nbsp;Glasgow.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Favorites:&nbsp;0&nbsp;&nbsp;Retweets:&nbsp;0</d></a><br><c>Literally desperate and just need to secure a nice room in a nice flat close to DJCAD so I can move in June 20th</c></div><div class="favourite-item" id="fav1"><button class="favouriteButton" id="favBut1"></button></div><div id="twitter-actions" style="opacity: 0; margin-top: -20px; display: none;"><div class="intent" id="intent-reply"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=462738657196376064" title="Reply"></a></div><div class="intent" id="intent-retweet"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=462738657196376064" title="Retweet"></a></div><div class="intent" id="intent-fave"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=462738657196376064" title="Favourite"></a></div></div></div>
```

Each one has a button assigned to it, which each also have individual IDs. 
I'm wanting to use the clone function to copy across the contents of say, '#tw1' into '#faveDiv'. #faveDiv been a div on my index.html page.

```
<div id="favouriteStreamHolder">
<div id="favouriteStream" style="display: none;">
<div id="faveDiv"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the clone function I'm trying

```
    $("input#favBut1").live( 'click', function(){


$('#faveDiv').html($('#tw1').html());
});
```

There's to much going on that relies on PHP that putting it into a simulator wouldn't achieve anything. Basically, that JS creates this. i.imgur.com/8yxLYBa.png A stream of 25 tweets of which the content is created in that js function having been pulled from a JSON file. I'm under the assumption that the .clone() function should copy all within the div and duplicate it into the div ive specified. At the moment. It's doing nothing, the div is just empty. Bit new to this, sorry. If theres anything else you need to know. Just say. 
Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What is it doing? What is it not doing? Can you place this in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so others can work with the code and see what is going on?

Comment: Sorry, easy to forget how much is going on. There's to much going on that relies on PHP that putting it into a simulator wouldn't achieve anything. 

Basically, that JS creates this. http://i.imgur.com/8yxLYBa.png

A stream of 25 tweets of which the content is created in that js function having been pulled from a JSON file. 

I'm under the assumption that the .clone() function should copy all within the div and duplicate it into the div ive specified. At the moment. It's doing nothing, the div is just empty. 

Bit new to this, sorry. If theres anything else you need to know. Just say.

Comment: If you can not debug your JavaScript because it is too tightly coupled to server side scripts then your in a world of hurt and have more pressing problems then the JavaScript not working. Best to separate concerns and modularize the code so that you can easily test your JavaScript independently from the server. That way the only thing that changes is the data not the logic.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be honest I'm a design student who doesn't know an awful lot of code and I'm hacking a lot of this together. I'm going to be doing the next prototype after I present this one. I know it's pretty badly coded and even I'm cringing at the file structures but, I think really this isn't so much the issue for why it's not working. 

Do you know if my function is correct for cloning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (pattern)

html

```
<div id="favouriteStreamHolder">
    <div id="favouriteStream">
        <div id="faveDiv"></div>
        <!-- 
         duplicate `favBut1` in `feedHTML`, 
         substitute `id` `feed` for `favBut1`
        -->
        <input type="button" id="feed" value="click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
// var feedHTML = `$.parseHTML(feedHTML)`   
var feedHTML = $.parseHTML('<div class="twitter-article" id="tw1">..</div>');
    $(document).on("click", "#feed", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).siblings("#faveDiv").html($(feedHTML));
    });
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ReK9u/

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for the answer. Sorry my reply is so late!

This almost works for me. It is indeed copying the div but all the content is empty. It is definetly copying the DIV and all its children but not the content within in. 

I assume its related to the fact that your content is already prefilled?